# Package gnome-shell-common has been held back but when trying to update it I get this

Tags: apt, gnome, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

When doing `sudo apt upgrade` it says 'gnome-shell-common has been held back'. When I do `sudo apt dist-upgrade` it doesn't show gnome-shell-common, and `sudo apt install gnome-shell-common` says it will remove ubuntu-session, ubuntu-desktop and more key packages. How do I fix this?

```
gnome-shell-common:
 Geïnstalleerd: 3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 
 Kandidaat: 3.28.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 
 Versietabel: 3.28.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 500  
  500  nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages 
  500  nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
  *** 3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 100 
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status 3.28.1-0ubuntu2 500 
 500 nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages 
 500 nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy gnome-shell-common` to the question.

Comment: gnome-shell-common:
  Geïnstalleerd: 3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
  Kandidaat:     3.28.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.2
  Versietabel:
     3.28.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 500
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
 *** 3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.28.1-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages

Comment: Did you forget to run `sudo apt update` before running `sudo apt dist-upgrade`?

Comment: This is affecting me as well. Of course `apt update` has been run.

Comment: I'm a third person experiencing this, so this seems to be a bug. More specifically, `libmutter` hasn't been upgraded in the bionic, which causes `gnome-shell` to fail to upgrade, which causes `gnome-shell-common` to fail: `gnome-shell : Depends: libmutter-2-0 (>= 3.28.3-1~ubuntu18.04.1) but 3.28.2-2~ubuntu18.04.1 is to be installed`. I guess the best thing to do is to wait.

Comment: Same issue and I just have  terminal!

Comment: Same issue here.

Comment: Same issue here

Comment: I did not read and pressed the enter and don't have gnome shell now, only terminal :( How long usually it takes for package maintainers to fix such problems?

Comment: @GregDan You probably should re-install 'ubuntu-desktop'

Comment: @YoranJansen I tried but package dependencies are broken now and installation fails. Hopefully I have a second computer.

Comment: They just fixed the dependencies and I was able to install all gnome 
 desktop packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error has been caused by them forgetting to update to a new version of the `libmutter` package, which is a dependency of the `gnome-shell` package (which itself is a dependency of `gnome-shell-common`):

`Depends: libmutter-2-0 (>= 3.28.3-1~ubuntu18.04.1) but 3.28.2-2~ubuntu18.04.1 is to be installed`

As of now, newer version of `libmutter` has been pushed, and you can now successfully upgrade both `gnome-shell` and `gnome-shell-common` packages.